# How to run sql script after automatic backup of Azure Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-backups

I'm looking for a way to run SQL script after automatic backup runs.
The main issue is that I have a huge data (Logging) and want to free the data of the database every period but backup it first. So I thought in running a script after the backup finish.
If anyone have another idea or know how to reach this approach, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The backups in Azure SQL DB are transparent and incremental.  So everything gets backed up and you can restore to any point in time.  It likely doesn't matter when the backups happen for your use case.  If you just want data to be deleted regularly based on some age or time-to-live, can you clarify your requirement?  It is likely that you can just run a delete script every N minutes and achieve your goal for now.